# Plotly/Dash - how to create two plots where a click in one defines the displayed window of the other?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly

How can one code the following click event in plotly (and/or dash)? Let us assume that we have two plots (e.g. a subplot or anything else that works). When a user clicks inside the top plot (either on a dot or anywhere inbetween), the x-value of the click-event (lets name it *xclick*) should be registered and used to update the x-axis range of the window in the bottom plot (i.e. display the range from *xclick* - 50 to *xclick* + 50).

To make this more clear, here is some sample code generating a time series (the idea is to display a window of it in the bottom plot) and the distances of its local maxima (displayed in the top plot, where ideally a click would define the window of the bottom plot):

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

# generate some random and relatively smooth time series
set.seed(114)
M <- 1000
r <- rnorm(M)
y <- cumsum(r)
x <- 1:length(y)
y <- loess(y~x, span = 0.15)$fitted

# cacluate the local maxima of time series
peaks <- ggpmisc:::find_peaks(y)
xpeaks <- x[peaks]

# plot 1: distances between local maxima of the time series
y1 <- xpeaks[2:length(xpeaks)]-xpeaks[1:(length(xpeaks)-1)]      # distance between successive peaks
x1 <- (xpeaks[2:length(xpeaks)]+xpeaks[1:(length(xpeaks)-1)])/2  # midpoint of successive peaks
data1 <- data.frame(y=y1,x=x1)
g1 <- ggplot(data1, aes(y=y, x = x)) + geom_point()
p1 <- ggplotly(g1)

# plot 2: window of the timeseries
x2 <- xpeaks[3] # here it is just some value, but x2 should become the clicked x-value in plot 1
timewindow <- (x2-50):(x2+50)  # select +-50 points around x2 to display
data2 <- data.frame(y=y[timewindow], x = x[timewindow])
g2 <- ggplot(data2, aes(x= x, y = y)) + geom_line()
p2 <- ggplotly(g2)

subplot(p1, p2, nrows = 2, heights = c(0.8,0.2))
```

Visually, this is what I wish to achieve:
[image]

Thank you for your kind help! Any small hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to take advantage of the plotly dash callback features.

https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks

I will walk you through a python example that I recently did. Sorry its not in R but hopefully you can fill in the gaps.

The basics of my build is I click on a map and it changes this weekend_score plot.

```
@app.callback(
    [Output('weekend_score', 'figure'),
    Output('map', 'figure')],
    [Input('weekend_score', 'clickData')
    Input('map','clickData'),
    Input('map','selectedData'))
```

The input to this callback are my map click or select events.

```
ctx = dash.callback_context
if ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'] == 'weekend_score.clickData':
     ws_indexes = [int(ws_data['points'][0]['curveNumber'])]
elif ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'] == 'map.clickData':
     indexes = [map_data['points'][0]['location']]
elif ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'] == 'map.selectedData':
     indexes = [x['location'] for x in map_selection['points']]
```

I then look through my actual events and see what triggered it. Depending of it was a click or a select I can go and get the indexes that were selected on my map.

```
return weekend_score_callback(session_id,ws_indexes), \
        get_map(map_indexes, session_id)
```

After accessing my indexes I return those indexes to the functions that rebuild my map and weekend score plot. Now the really tricky thing here is building your plots in the first place such that you could identify them from the callback and then change them with those in mind. For me I have a unique identifier attached to every object in my map and in my trend line. For example if I click on the map object with ID=1 then it gets passed through the callback and ends up in my weekend_score_callback function, I then go into my dataframe and only pull out the ID=1 datapoint and plot that on my weekend score plot.